# Magento and Wordpress - $_GET variable disappears from query_string

Tags: wordpress, url, magento, redirect, get

In a Wordpress+Magento integrated environment, I have a form in Wordpress that submits to another wordpress page. This form has an input field with the name of "zip". When this form submits, the "zip" seems to not make it to the receiving page. I can see it go through, in the network console, but doing a var_dump on $_GET (on the receiving page) comes up empty.

I've looked at solutions online that include installing a plug-in and also trying to add the variable into query_vars, but neither of these seemed to resolve the issue.

I suspect that there is some redirect happening, in Magento/Apache or Wordpress that is stripping off the GET parameters.

Thoughts/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

IndexController.php was modified and it was not forwarding the POST/GET variables.

I was able to modify the code to forward the variables and the issue has been resolved.

Comment: hey, which indexcontroller.php did you modify to let this through? and where did it live in the file structure?

Comment: i don't recall now where it was. if you have multiple in your installation, try modifying each one until you find it.